# How can I decode to an embedded struct?

Tags: json, go, struct, decode

I wish to be able to use `.Decode()` on a response body to populate a struct without first having to attempt to figure out which type of struct I should decode to.

I have a generic struct `Match` to hold information about a game that was played e.g. a match in Fortnite. Within this struct, I use `MatchData` to hold the entirety of the game's match data.

When decoding into the `MatchData` struct, I'm finding the underlying embedded type is initialised, but with all default values, and not the values from the respose.

```
type Match struct {
    MatchID       int        `json:"match_id"`
    GameType      int        `json:"game_type"`
    MatchData     *MatchData `json:"match_data"`
}

type MatchData struct {
    MatchGame1
    MatchGame2
}

type MatchGame1 struct {
    X int `json:"x"`
    Y int `json:"y"`
}

type MatchGame2 struct {
    X int `json:"x"`
    Y int `json:"y"`
}

func populateData(m *Match) (Match, error) {
    response, err := http.Get("game1.com/path")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    
    // Here, m.MatchData is set with X and Y equal to 0
    // when response contains values > 0
    err = json.NewDecoder(response.Body).Decode(&m.MatchData)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return m, nil
}
```

**Edit**
Example expected JSON payload.

```
{
    "x": 10,
    "y": 20
}
```

I can solve the issue by checking `m.GameType`, creating a struct that corresponds and then assigning it to `m.MatchData`, but if I wanted to add another 100 game APIs, I'd prefer if the function could be agnostic of it.

I'm not sure if this is even possible, but thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you also post an expected JSON payload?

Comment: Yes, apologies. The actual responses are a lot more complex, but just as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach in the question will not work because the embedded structs share field names. Try this approach.

Declare a map that associates game type identifiers with the associated Go types. This is only code related to decoding that knows about the hundreds of game types.

```
var gameTypes = map[int]reflect.Type{
    1: reflect.TypeOf(&MatchGame1{}),
    2: reflect.TypeOf(&MatchGame2{}),
}
```

Decode the match data to a [raw message](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#RawMessage). Use the game type to create a match data value and decode to that value.

```
func decodeMatch(r io.Reader) (*Match, error) {

    // Start with match data set to a raw messae.
    var raw json.RawMessage
    m := &Match{MatchData: &raw}

    err := json.NewDecoder(r).Decode(m)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    m.MatchData = nil

    // We are done if there's no raw message.
    if len(raw) == 0 {
        return m, nil
    }

    // Create the required match data value.
    t := gameTypes[m.GameType]
    if t == nil {
        return nil, errors.New("unknown game type")
    }
    m.MatchData = reflect.New(t.Elem()).Interface()

    // Decode the raw message to the match data.
    return m, json.Unmarshal(raw, m.MatchData)

}
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Zy-ooImvTMH).